# How to Connect a Display Port output to a USB-C Monitor?

Tags: displayport, usb-c

**It is possible to connect a *Display Port* or *Mini Display Port* output to a USB-C Display input? If, so what adapter and/or cables are required?**

It would seem they use the same display protocol and I am finding plenty of adapters that go from USB-C to Display Port but not the opposite way. What is needed is a cable or adapters to connect a DisplayPort female plug to a USB-C female plug. Of course, DisplayPort does not carry power but this should not be necessary in this case since one USB-C Monitor that I have has 2 USB-C ports and the other has a USB-C input and separate power plug.

A [page from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000141328/displayport-over-usb-type-c#:%7E:text=USB%20Type%2DC%3F-,Yes.,DVI%2C%20and%20VGA%20monitor%20inputs.) says it is possible but no indication as to how:

> Can I connect an existing monitor to a new computer, tablet or phone
> that uses the USB-C connector with DisplayPort over USB-C? Yes.
> Adapters and Adapter cables are available to connect DisplayPort over
> USB-C to DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI, and VGA monitor inputs.

Comment: Well I was looking into it - USB C/DP cables are directional - USB C on the PC to DP on the monitor *but* (more expensive) bidirectional cables exist. Never really got around to testing it though

Comment: So far, I've only found directional one... and the other direction. I've spent hours search over several days and nothing so far.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-Bidirectional-Type-C-DisplayPort-Cable/dp/B084HP1DZY for example

Comment: Oddly enough all the reviews on that adapter says the description is wrong and it is unidirectional but this is a good starting point! Might exist even :)

Comment: Might be a question for our sister site - hardware recommendations then. I have an aliexpress one on order and might update/answer that if it does work

Answer (score 3):

Well I was looking into it - USB C/DP cables are directional - USB C on the PC to DP on the dev *but* (more expensive) bidirectional cables exist. There also seem to be 'converters' for this which appear to be active devices. The 'critical' thing here is bidirectionality.